# What is the name of this android menu and how to implement it

Tags: android, view, menu

I could have searched for how to implement it but I don't even know its name
[Facebook menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC0VX.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called Bottom Sheet. Follow this link if you want the details on how to implement it https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment/ and here is the official doc https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment